# Checking for new elements on a existing webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

What would be the best way to check for new elements on a specific part of a webpage, looping infinitely? When a new element is added/found, the script continues.

I'm currently thinking about using function checkDOMChange() for this purpose, but i'm not sure if it would work.

As you can see, i'm new to JavaScript and coding in general.

Comment: Please provide more details in your question or it may be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DOMNodeInserted` event to detect a creation of new element.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/yLs39b3a/1/)

Here, I've created an example that has a 5s delay before a new `div` is created.

#### HTML:

```
<div id="main">This is...... I don't know. Something</div><br />
```

#### JavaScript:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('main');

setTimeout(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('div');
    elem.appendChild(e.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Newly created Div')))
}, 5000);

// this will be triggered if any new element is appended to div#main
elem.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (ev) {
  alert('New element detected')
}, false);
```

Comment: How would the code be if i just want to detect the creation of a new element on the page, in general?